# Can we get list of fields(matadata)

Tags: code

I need something like this

```
**Field       Label     Field Name/API Name      Data Type**

Standard    Campaign    Campaign                 Lookup(Campaign)

Standard    City        City                     Text(40)
.......
```

I have more than 1000 fields so it's going very hard for me to add manually.

Comment: What's the use case for needing this (specifically from the Dev Console)? There's plenty of easy ways to get it using other tools...

Comment: not specially dev console. can you tell me about tool and how it works ?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know why you're asking. I need to know what you need this data for in order to best direct any answer I'd give you.

Comment: I need a file with object fields information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a file containing all field information, consider using the Force.com IDE or the Metadata Toolkit. For the Force.com IDE, just set up a new project, login, and choose the object(s) you want. Once the project refreshes, you'll have files like this:

```
+ src
--+ objects
  --+ Account.object
  --+ Contact.object
  --+ MyCustomObj.object
```

Each file contains all of the metadata, but you have to parse it somehow. I used Excel macros a few years ago to massage the data into a handy spreadsheet, but I no longer have the scripts. It wouldn't take too long to write something up in VBScript.

Alternatively, also in the Force.com IDE, you can go to the schema file, and when you open it, you'll get a browsing interface that lets you see the data types, labels, and so on for every field, organized by object. You can also build queries from here and view the results.

The Metadata Toolkit is much of the same, but without the GUI. You can retrieve all the files you want, and you'll have the same XML files. Again, you might need to figure a way to translate the data from XML to whatever format you want. There's other ways you could access this data, but I find that using tools is usually preferable to not.

Answer (score 3):

[image]I just developed the code after clashing with this question. See if it could work for you. For the time being, i hard coded object api name but you can set it from custom setting or in page parameter. You can download a pdf of any object you want. You just copy this code as is. It will surely meet your needs.

public class FieldsMetaDataController {

```
public List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> listOfFieldResults { get; set; }

public FieldsMetaDataController() {
    setPDFData();
}

private void setPDFData() {

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mapOfGlobalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    if( mapOfGlobalDescription != NULL && !mapOfGlobalDescription.isEmpty() ) {

        Schema.SObjectType sObjType = mapOfGlobalDescription.get( 'Account' );
        if( sObjType != NULL ) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjResult = sObjType.getDescribe();

            if( sObjResult != NULL ) {
                Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapOfObjectFieldResults = sObjResult.fields.getMap();
                listOfFieldResults = new List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
                for ( String strFieldResult : mapOfObjectFieldResults.keySet() ) {
                    listOfFieldResults.add( mapOfObjectFieldResults.get(strFieldResult).getDescribe() );    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<!-- Field Results -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! listOfFieldResults <> NULL }">

    <table class="dataTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style="width:100%">

            <thead>
                <th> Label </th>
                <th> Api Name </th>
                <th> Type </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat var="recordFieldResult" value="{! listOfFieldResults }">
                    <tr>  
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{! recordFieldResult.Label }"/>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{! recordFieldResult.Name}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{! recordFieldResult.Type }"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>

        </table>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! listOfFieldResults == NULL }">
    <h5> Sorry, No Fields are available. Please contact System Administrator. </h5>
</apex:outputPanel>
```